# Lolcode: variable does not exist: STDIO

Tags: windows, lolcode

I got the following problem while trying to run a LOLCODE program:

```
variable does not exist: STDIO
```

I think it's something with me running on Windows instead of any linux. I want to use LOLCODE for a school assignment, as in my opinion just using Python would be too easy.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue while trying to use `STDIO` for file I/O.
Turns out you must use the `future` branch of `lci` for that functionality.

Simply do,
`git clone -b future https://github.com/justinmeza/lci.git`.

then,
If on linux use `python3 install.py`.
For windows follow the [official guide](https://github.com/justinmeza/lci#installation-on-windows).